# Not enough storage is available to complete this operation in ExcelSheet

Tags: c#, excel

I'm working on Excelsheet of .xls extensions with 4 Sheets in it. I'm writing xml content to all these sheets.After writing to each sheet I'm Saving and Collecting the Garbage using this method

```
 private static void SaveAndCollecttheGarbage(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp, string path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheet)
 {
    try
    {
        excelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
        mWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        mWorkBook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        sheet = null;
        mWorkBook = null;
        excelApplication.Quit();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

This is working fine for all my first 3 sheets but when coming to the my 4th sheet it is throwing an error when the cell value is *--------Original------and the data goes on.....*

**Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000E (E_OUTOFMEMORY))**

My 4th sheet has more data (1100+ **rows**) than the other sheets. This is how I'm writing data to my 4th sheet

```
mWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(excelPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false); 
                        mSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;
                        mWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)mSheets.Add();
                        mWorkSheet.Name = "Case History";
                        int l = 1, m = 1, n = 0;
                        mWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Id";
                        mWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Subject";
                        mWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "CustomerHistory";
                        foreach (CaseHistory customerHistory in allCustomerHistory)
                        {
                            n = 0;
                            mWorkSheet.Cells[l + m, ++n] = customerHistory.id;
                            mWorkSheet.Cells[l + m, ++n] = customerHistory.caseSubject;
                            mWorkSheet.Cells[l + m, ++n] = customerHistory.caseBody;
                            m++;
                        }
```

I cannot find what I'm doing wrong. Isn't it possible to write huge data to excelsheet. If can do help me how to do it

Comment: Does this situation still occur if you leave the GC alone and let it do its job when it decides to?

Comment: No,I haven't tried leaving GC alone.

Comment: Its the same problem even I after leaving GC collector

Comment: Can you provide the complete backtrace of the out-of-memory exception you're getting?

Comment: At what point in the code are you getting the error?  I have seen similar errors when I accidentally try to format every cell in the worksheet (except for 1 or something) so Excel goes crazy trying to do it.  It's possible your call to `AutoFit` is causing a form of that.  Why are you doing `excelApp.Columns.AutoFit` instead of `sheet.Columns.AutoFit` or even better `sheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit`?  The last one will not try to process all 16384 columns in the worksheet and will only do the used ones.

Comment: And the type of `sheet` should be `...Excel.Worksheet` not Worksheet**s** if you actually want a single `Worksheet` (and the `AutoFit` to work).  It seems you don't use that reference anywhere though.

Comment: You might be right but I don't think that  'AutoFit' is causing the problem,Are there any specifications that a column shouldn't start with special characters? @Byron

Comment: "Start with"?  What does that mean?  So far as I am aware, there are no limitations to what values are allowed in a cell.  Can you confirm where the error occurs and update your question with that info for others?